# What complementary method to 'reproject', in a composite function, is necessary for preserving original resolution in an Image Collection with GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Following GEE code determines relative humidity (RH) in a point of land surface by using considerations exposed in [this question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/how-do-i-convert-specific-humidity-to-relative-humidity) and 'NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H' products. Some individual values for pressure, temperature and specific humidity, also obtained from 'NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H' products, were used for calculating relative humidity in a spreadsheet, with Clausius-Clapeyron formula, and results were identical to obtained with GEE ([link to script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/070cf9340778d33302bc112d7f731002)).

```
var startDate = ee.Date('1981-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('1981-01-03');

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

var imageScale = ee.Image(dataset
  .first())
  .projection().nominalScale();

print('Scale:', imageScale);

var count = dataset.size();

print("count original", count);

var days = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days');
var daysStep = 1;

var timeSeries = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, days.subtract(1), daysStep)
    .map(function (offsetDays) {
      var start = startDate.advance(offsetDays, 'days');
      var end = start.advance(daysStep, 'days');
      var composite = dataset  // former lst
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .min(); // You need to decide how to combine the images
      return composite
        .reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 27829.87269831839)
        .set('system:time_start', start.millis())
        .set('empty', composite.bandNames().size().eq(0));
    })
  ).filterMetadata('empty', 'equals', 0);

print("count composite", timeSeries.size());

print("New Scale", timeSeries.first().projection().nominalScale());

var p = ee.Geometry.Point(-70.2166985,-38.5275513); //p18

var getDateHumidity = function(image) {

  // Reducing region and getting value
  var value_hum = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), p)
    .get('Qair_f_inst');

  var value_pres = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), p)
    .get('Psurf_f_inst');
    
  var value_temp = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), p)
    .get('Tair_f_inst');
  
  var f = ee.Number(0.00263)
    .multiply(ee.Number(value_hum))
    .multiply(ee.Number(value_pres));
  
  var g = ee.Number(17.67)
    .multiply(ee.Number(value_temp)
    .subtract(ee.Number(273.16))
    .divide(ee.Number(value_temp).subtract(ee.Number(29.65))))
    .exp();
  
  var h = f.divide(g);
    
  var time = ee.Image(image).get('system:time_start');
  
  // Return the time (in milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970) as a Date
  var humidity_list = ee.Date(time)
    .format()
    .slice(0,10)
    .split('-')
    .add(h);
  
  return humidity_list;
};

var humidity_list1 = dataset.toList(count).map(getDateHumidity);

var myFeatures1 = ee.FeatureCollection(humidity_list1.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list
  var geom = p;
  return ee.Feature(geom, {
    'year':ee.Number(el.get(0)), 
    'month':ee.Number(el.get(1)),
    'day':ee.Number(el.get(2)),
    'value':ee.Number(el.get(3))
  });
}));


//print(myFeatures1);

var humidity_list2 = timeSeries.toList(count).map(getDateHumidity);

//print(humidity_list);

var myFeatures2 = ee.FeatureCollection(humidity_list2.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list
  var geom = p;
  return ee.Feature(geom, {
    'year':ee.Number(el.get(0)), 
    'month':ee.Number(el.get(1)),
    'day':ee.Number(el.get(2)),
    'value':ee.Number(el.get(3))
  });
}));

//Map.addLayer(myFeatures); // see the result
//Map.centerObject(myFeatures, 8);

//print(myFeatures2);


// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: myFeatures1,
  folder: "GEE_Folder", //my export folder
  description: 'daily_humidity',  //file name
  fileFormat: "CSV"});

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: myFeatures2,
  folder: "GEE_Folder", //my export folder
  description: 'daily_humidity',  //file name
  fileFormat: "CSV"});
```

Above script determines RH for an Image Collection with 8 images per day (each 3 hours) and RH for a composite of these eight daily images. Obtained values are exported to Google Drive and, in above example with used dates, were printed 16 values in first case and only 2 with composite function. Results are as follows:

16 values

```
1,1,1981,0.541049210101378
1,1,1981,0.612131423086637
1,1,1981,0.712494530538605
1,1,1981,0.732241931627969
1,1,1981,0.675578926045453
1,1,1981,0.582798200402885
1,1,1981,0.451271023830914
1,1,1981,0.400543900671863
2,1,1981,0.430912988431544
2,1,1981,0.513416664811639
2,1,1981,0.646455860743016
2,1,1981,0.727504186156708
2,1,1981,0.753175972018466
2,1,1981,0.681819169670857
2,1,1981,0.511359249899844
2,1,1981,0.428261514810568
```

2 values

```
1,1,1981,0.709153505818986
2,1,1981,0.537754061477617
```

As it can be observed in the script, I used a 'min' method in composite function for selecting RH values. However, above obtained values are very different from following two expected values:

```
1,1,1981,0.400543900671863
2,1,1981,0.428261514810568
```

I searched for the reason of this unexpected result and I [found out](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections#the-default-projection) that composite images are produced in GEE with the default projection; which is WGS84 with 1-degree scale. This is very different from original nominal scale of 'NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H': 27829.87269831839 meters (0.25 arc degrees). So, I had to use following reproject method (.reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 27829.87269831839)) in composite function for finally run my script and to get that nominal scale.

On the other hand, only for curiosity, I changed 'min' method for 'max' and I also got following weird results:

```
1,1,1981,0.46162372954395
2,1,1981,0.640986494579716
```

So, is it necessary to use another (or other) complementary method with 'reproject', in a composite function, for obtaining expected result of true minimum values and preserve original resolution of 0.25 arc degrees?

**Editing Note:**

@Nicholas Clinton pointed out in his answer that the affirmation of "composite images are produced in GEE with the default projection" is not entirely right. It was simply found [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections#the-default-projection). However, without following instruction in composite function:

```
.reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 27829.87269831839)
```

when I tried to print **Feature Collection** obtained with **Image Collection** in composite function, without any "reprojection", it was displayed the error message of following image where it pointed out: "The WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform". Similar message was obtained when I tried to run the task. On the other hand, it can be also observed that scale of aggregated **Image Collection** is [111319.49079327357 m](https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/approx_equivalents.htm) (equivalent to 1 arc degree); as mentioned in the previous link.

[image]

On the other hand, after reading [link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale#scale-of-analysis) in Nicholas Clinton's answer, I adapted code for my **ImageCollection**:

```
var p = ee.Geometry.Point(-70.2166985,-38.5275513); //p18

var image = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H')
  .first()
  .select("Qair_f_inst");

print(image);

var printAtScale = function(scale) {
  print('Pixel value at ' + scale + ' meters scale',
    image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
      geometry: p,
      // The scale determines the pyramid level from which to pull the input
      scale: scale
  }).get("Qair_f_inst"));
};

printAtScale(100); // 8883
printAtScale(1000); // 9215
printAtScale(10000); // 8775
printAtScale(100000); // 8300
printAtScale(1000000); // 8300
```

and result evidences a scale issue:

[image]

The problem is increasing by errors propagating because relative humidity is the combination of other bands and constants in the Clausius-Clapeyron equation. So, it seems that I need one way for retrieving former scale in composite series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution by using **ee.List** objects. First, I created a list with only relative humidity values iterating on original list with a function. Afterward, I sliced that list in groups of 8 elements where min values were determined. These values were stored in a new list and they were as expected.

```
var startDate = ee.Date('1981-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('1981-04-01');

var p = ee.Geometry.Point(-70.2166985,-38.5275513); //p18

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

var list_dataset = dataset.toList(dataset.size());

//print(list_dataset);

var getRelativeHumidity = function(image) {

  // Reducing region and getting value
  var value_hum = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), p)
    .get('Qair_f_inst');

  var value_pres = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), p)
    .get('Psurf_f_inst');

  var value_temp = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), p)
    .get('Tair_f_inst');

  var f = ee.Number(0.00263)
    .multiply(ee.Number(value_hum))
    .multiply(ee.Number(value_pres));

  var g = ee.Number(17.67)
    .multiply(ee.Number(value_temp)
    .subtract(ee.Number(273.16))
    .divide(ee.Number(value_temp).subtract(ee.Number(29.65))))
    .exp();

  var h = f.divide(g);

  var time = ee.Image(image).get('system:time_start');

  // Return the time (in milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970) as a Date
  var humidity_list = h; 

  return humidity_list;
};

var count = dataset.size();

var hum_list = dataset.toList(count).map(getRelativeHumidity);

//print("humidity list", hum_list);

var allDates = ee.List(dataset.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  }).distinct();

var len = hum_list.size();

var list = ee.List.sequence(0, len.subtract(1), 8);

var min_hum_list = list.map(function(ele){

  var start = ee.Number(ele).int(); 
  var end = ee.Number(ele).add(8).int(); 

  var new_list = ee.List([]);
  var element = ee.List(hum_list.slice(start, end)).reduce(ee.Reducer.min());

  new_list = new_list.add(element);

  return new_list;

}).flatten();

var paired = allDatesSimple.zip(min_hum_list);

//print (paired);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(paired.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list
  var geom = p;
  return ee.Feature(geom, {
    'date': ee.String(el.get(0)),
    'value':ee.Number(el.get(1))
  });
}));

//print(myFeatures);

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"humedad", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"dayly_hum_min_p",  //file name
"CSV");
```

After running script, following values were printed for original list.

```
0: 0.5410492101013781
1: 0.6121314230866369
2: 0.7124945305386051
3: 0.7322419316279689
4: 0.6755789260454528
5: 0.5827982004028849
6: 0.451271023830914
7: 0.4005439006718627
8: 0.430912988431544
9: 0.5134166648116385
10: 0.6464558607430163
11: 0.7275041861567081
12: 0.7531759720184658
13: 0.6818191696708572
14: 0.511359249899844
15: 0.42826151481056796
16: 0.4330844926689814
17: 0.5064309937145617
18: 0.6474067363946048
19: 0.6849807488756209
20: 0.6194320104912739
21: 0.5297404218531643
22: 0.4120223030722458
23: 0.3556466153145915
```

Below values corresponding to min for groups of 8 elements. Twenty four values of this climatic element in original series were reduced to only three values as expected.

```
0: 0.4005439006718627
1: 0.42826151481056796
2: 0.3556466153145915
```

Now, time for producing these values in relatively long series it was reduced drastically.

Answer (score 1):

This is not entirely right: "composite images are *produced* in GEE with the default projection."  Although it might seem that way, the composite is not "produced" until you ask for it, by exporting for example.  See [this doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale#scale-of-analysis) for more information.  At that time, the inputs are requested in the output projection and scale, which you specify in the `Export` call.  There is no need for `reproject`.  It's better to think of those composites as being *labeled* with the default projection, because Earth Engine doesn't know what you really want yet.